# Unable to increase the height of UIView in relation to TextView

Tags: ios, uistackview, xcode10

[image]

I used the vertical stack view to hold two UIView.Second UIView has a textArea.But I could not find a way to change the UIview height when the height of TextView change

Comment: https://github.com/KennethTsang/GrowingTextView

Comment: @kasun did you disable scroll of UITextView ?